# How to set Fish as the default vagrand shell on debian, with the box accessed from IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, vagrant, fish

I installed fish 2.1 on a Debian. I tried to set it as the default shell using chsh.

When I reestablish an SSH session to the vagrant box, the shell is still bash. (all the commands below are run as vagrant user)

echo $SHELL ==> /bin/bash

sudo chsh ==> shows the Login shell as /usr/bin/fish (default value)

/etc/passwd shows that vagrand user has the shell /usr/bin/fish

I'm connecting via IntelliJ Idea, and I haven't see any configuration to override the shell If I connect using Putty, the default shell is indeed Fish

What am I missing ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Used chsh, and it claims it should be fish, but doesn't run on `vagrant ssh`. I can manually enter the fish shell after ssh, but I want it to run on startup. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

To change shell to Fish, do a following:

```
sudo chsh -s $(which fish) $(whoami)
```

Here is a link: https://coolaj86.com/articles/getting-started-with-vagrant.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean vagrant?

Just do `$ chsh -s /usr/bin/fish` and restart your shell.